# SQLInsert'ing Null into a table (not SQLite)

Tags: databaselink, sql

Is it possible to insert `Null` values using DatabaseLink, without formatting the query string manually?

Hans found (below) that this works for SQLite, so it appears this may driver-specific. I have tested it on MySQL, Postgresql, and Amazon Redshift.

For example:

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", host],
  "Username" -> user, "Password" -> pass];
SQLExecute[conn, "create table public.test (i integer null)"];
SQLInsert[conn, "public.test", {"i"}, {Null}]
```

> > [Amazon]JDBC Error converting data, invalid type for
> >     parameter: 1.

Comment: I have tested this on MySQL and it works with *Mathematica* 10.2.

Comment: I'm on 10.2 also. Are you using a local MySQL instance? I am using RDS, I did not try spinning up a local DB. Maybe it is specific to RDS?

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. I'm using a local instance.

Answer (score 4):

Using the built in SQLite you may try the following

```
    Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite(Memory)", ""]];
SQLCreateTable[conn, 
  SQLTable["TEST"], {SQLColumn["i", "DataTypeName" -> "INTEGER", 
    "Nullable" -> True]}];
SQLInsert[conn, "TEST", {"i"}, {Null}]
SQLSelect[conn, "TEST"]
SQLDropTable[conn, "TEST"];
CloseSQLConnection[conn];
```

The key here is the SQL table schema definition for the column to allow nulls, or to be or accept "Null". There is a Default attribute which can be set to Null also. If you were to use `SQLExecute[]` then try the following:

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite(Memory)", ""]];
SQLExecute[conn, "create table TEST (i integer null)"];
SQLInsert[conn, "TEST", {"i"}, {Null}]
SQLSelect[conn, "TEST"]
SQLDropTable[conn, "TEST"];
CloseSQLConnection[conn];
```

There may be a global setting to Allow Null on or off in some databases if I recall correctly.

I also checked this on an instance of MS SQL Server 2012 and had no issues. Also used `SQLExecute[]` to insert parameters.

```
SQLExecute[conn, "INSERT INTO TEST (i) VALUES (?)", {Null}]
```

All on Windows 8.1 M 10.0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I had not tried SQLite. The columns are nullable in my situation (and SQLInsert still does not work) -- I will add more information.

Comment: @mfvonh if you change "Nullable" -> False the insert does not work in SQLite. More information may be helpful.