# How to specify NULL when inserting data into SQL Server using SQLExecute

Tags: java, sql, databaselink

I have an Microsoft SQL Server connection using:

```
$connection=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(microsoft)",StringJoin["...;databaseName=...;integratedSecurity=true"]]];
```

I am executing the following SQL:

```
SQLExecute[$connection,"INSERT INTO [table](
   [Col1],
   [Col2],
   [Col3]
)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
$data]
```

The `Col3` is `FLOAT` and whenever Null appears in $data it errors out. I tried replacing the `Null` with `"Null"` or `""`.

- `Null` gives JDBC: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with float.
- `"Null"` gives JDBC: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
- `""` works but adds zeros. I want to add NULL.

Please help! Btw all columns allow NULLs in the table schema.

I don't understand why it interprets the `Null` as varbinary.

Also, I tried `SQLInsert` command directly with the same results.

Comment: what happens if you simply supply nothing for that column? as in `Values(1,2, , 4,5)` ? If the column is defined without NOT NULL then database should automatically insert NULL there. something to try anyway.

Comment: When i replace them by `“”` i am assuming thats what it is doing right? The `?` in the query will get replaced by `“”` right? Also i am doing bulk insert of millions of records.

Comment: No, do not add `""` or anything, just do it as I showed.  Try it on one row and see if it works or not.  I can't try it myself.

Comment: Which SQL server are you using? In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91796/75628), for example, the user had no problems inserting null values to the MS SQL server database ... Does his simple code work for you?